# Error opening SHP file in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-maptools

I am using maptools to open a shapefile in R, but I get the following error in Rstudio:

```
library(maptools)
basins = readShapeSpatial("H:GIS/shapefiles/basins")
Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file
```

When I try the exact same code in RGui (instead of Rstudio) it works! I would like to keep using Rstudio as it is so convenient so anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Your drive name 'H:GIS' appears to be non standard. Have you forgotten a `/`

Comment: ups, that solves it... wonder why it worked on RGUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer as to why it works in `Rstudio`, but the issue is that your drive path / drive name is non-standard

```
 'H:/GIS/shapefiles/basins'
```

is more standard, and works in both.